# Does there exist a type of metal serrated sheet to place between two mating surfaces?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cnc

I'm trying to design a bolted joint between 2 aluminum members that will not shift in sheer under vibration loads.

The two straight members form a cross shape. Right now there are simply tight tolerance holes in the two parts and they are bolted together with 2x 5/16-18 bolts. There are 2 holes in each part where the parts cross, and they are approximately 2in apart.

This is fine and it's fairly stiff. But a foot or so from the joint I imagine there will be some play. It can't be felt normally because of the clamping force from the bolts, but the vibration will be able to shift the joint over time, causing inaccuracy in the CNC.

What I was thinking would be ideal to solve this, is some kind of serrated sheet I could place between the two members. It would be made of harder metal then the aluminum, so when the clamping force is applied, it would sink into the aluminum surface on both sides, and effectively lock them together, allowing zero wiggle.

Does such a thing exist? I know I can use pins and other tight tolerance techniques, but I don't need tight tolerances, I just need to eliminate drift.

Comment: A serrated washer?

Comment: Not sure why you don't just use pins. If you don't need tight tolerances it just means you don't have to align so carefully before pinning.

Comment: @DKNguyen The parts will be manufactured separately and then assembled by a technician. I don't want that person to have to do any machining operations. If the pin holes were pre-drilled they would have to be extremely accurate and tight to have any effect.

Comment: Plus match drilling through the 2 parts to pin them results in non-interchangeable parts.

Comment: @SolarMike I basically want a serrated sheet, not just a washer.

Comment: This is close, but I don't think the metal teeth would be strong enough to dig into aluminum:  https://materialdistrict.com/material/grip-metal/

Comment: Aliminium compresses easily - why electrical connections can come loose . Also it will deform just through tightening bolts.

Comment: What if you installed a pointed setscrew beside each bolt?

Comment: They will have metal teeth for just about any material.  You've found your answer it seems.  If all else fails, you can weld the parts together.

Comment: This is not a standard part because in the real world this is not a problem.  Even with vibration, clamping force does not go through zero. Even with vibration such that clamping force goes through zero, the parts will only drift if there is lateral force.

Comment: @david I am in the real world working on a real mechanism, and I have the problem. This is not actually a CNC machine, it's more like a robot, and it gets banged around. I assure you that it does shift.